# Installing Ubuntu in Sony Vaio svf15213

Tags: 12.10, windows-8

My Laptop is Sony Vaio SVF15213SN. It comes with preinstalled windows 8 64bit.
I tried to install Ubuntu 12.10 32 bit along with this windows by changing BIOS settings from UEFI to legacy mode. Instalation was success. But i cant login to windows as it says some boot error. If i switch back to UEFI mode then im able to use windows but not Ubuntu. Is there a solution for this.